# Understanding Ptolemy's Almagest

Tags: archaeoastronomy, ptolemy

This is an extract from page 138 of Ptolemy's Almagest (Toomer):

> [Hipparchus] made a very accurate observation of the autumnal equinox, and says that he calculated that it occurred at midnight, third-fourth epagomenal day [-146 Sept. 26/27]. The year is the 178th from the death of Alexander. 285 years later, in the third year of Antoninus, which is the 463rd from the death of Alexander, we observed, again very securely, that the autumnal equinox occurred on Athyr 9 [139 Sept. 26], approximately one hour after sunrise. Therefore the period of return comprised, over 285 complete Egyptian years (that is years of 365 days), 70$\frac{1}{4}$ days plus approximately $\frac{1}{20}$th of a day, instead of the 71$\frac{1}{4}$ days corresponding to the $\frac{1}{4}$-day surplus for the above [285] years. Thus the return took place earlier than it would have with the [365]$\frac{1}{4}$-day year by one day less about $\frac{1}{20}$th day.

How does Ptolemy calculate the $\frac{1}{20}$th of a day? Shouldn't this be $\frac{7}{24}$ assuming sunrise is at 6am on an equinox?
So the equinox is early by $\frac{17}{24}$th of a day instead of $\frac{19}{20}$th of a day as he states later in the text, right?